# Create Bitmap from Layout excluding selected views

Tags: android, layout, bitmap, view

I am able to create a Bitmap from a FrameLayout using this method:

```
public Bitmap layoutToBitmap(FrameLayout layout) {

        layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        if (layout != null) {
            layout.destroyDrawingCache();
        }

        layout.buildDrawingCache();

        Bitmap bm = layout.getDrawingCache();
        return bm;
    }
```

My question is if I can do the exact same thing, but excluding some of the views which are inside the FrameLayout.

It is worth to mention that the previous method is called from within an AsyncTask.

Comment: I guess you would need to hide the views temporarily, taking the snapshot, then show them again. Also I'm surprised your code works from outside the UI thread.

Comment: It works because I do not modify any content of the UI thread. But I am not allowed to modify the visibility of the views inside the FrameLayout.

Comment: you would need to do that stuff from the UI thread or call context.runOnUiThread to modify the visibility. also I'd say it's a miracle Android doesn't throw the exception if you build the cache outside the UI thread: The view can be modified while the system is creating the image.

Comment: Do you think I can do this directly from the UI thread?

Comment: I think you should, but I don't have evidence, just looked at the View.java source code and the buildViewCache function is pretty complicated, calling a lot of View methods. If it works from another thread maybe it's fine. But to modify the visibility you definitely must do it from the UI thread.

Comment: Changing the visibility and calling the method from the UI thread solved it, thanks @rupps !!